# How to display name instead of ID when there is no foreign key in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I have asked a similar question to this one and I tried to fix this part of the code with that answer that I got but unfortunately, it doesn't work and I think the case is that this table does not have a foreign key and the problem is that I cant make it for this table because that show it's supposed to work it can't have a foreign key(no because something isn't working it's just because that's how I must make the project)

So I just wanted to let you know that I cannot use foreign key but I was wondering if it's still possible to access the ID of the user and get the name

The leave controller stores the user_id when the authenticated user creates a leave request

Heres the Leave Controller for Index:

```
public function index()
{

    
    if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $leaves = Leave::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin/leave/index', compact('leaves'),compact('users'));
    }
}
```

The Leave Controller when it stores the user_id so the ID of the user who is logged in at that time

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'from'=>'required',
        'to'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required', 
        'type'=>'required'
        ]);
        $data=$request->all();
        $data['user_id']=auth()->user()->id;
        $data['message']='';
        $data['status']=0;
        $leave =Leave::create($data);
```

Theres extra code that is used for another function then it redirects it but i think that wasnt related to this part so i didnt include that.

The Leave Model :

```
class Leave extends Model

{

use Notifiable;

protected $guarded=[];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');   
 }
}
```

And this is the view where I want to see the name instead of ID

```
 @foreach($leaves as $leave)
                      <tr>
                        <th>{{$leave->user_id}} {{$leave->user_id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$leave->from}}</td>
                        <td>{{$leave->to}}</td>
                        <td>{{$leave->description}}</td>
                        <td>{{$leave->type}}</td>
                        <td>{{$leave->message}}</td>
                        <td>
```

I want this part to show the first_name which is the field for the users name of that ID that was stored

```
<th>{{$leave->user_id}} {{$leave->user_id}}</th>
```

I have tried using the $leave->user_id->first_name but it didnt work

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `compact` accepts multiple parameters, `return view('admin/leave/index', compact('leaves', 'users'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call function from model `$leave->user->first_name`. I have added it as below.

```
<th>{{$leave->user->first_name}}</th>
```

You've made `user()`  as `belongsTo` relation so now you can access it by using

```
$leave->functionname->fieldname
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to understand the use of Model relationship defining function. Without any usage why you define the function in Model. So you can use that function when you retry or store leave data.

For retry you can use like `{{$leave->user->first_name}}` in blade and you can use like `$leave->user()->first_name` in your controller. More info check [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)